# ros2_control want to set parameter from cli, serial port

Tags: ros-humble, hardware-interface, diff-drive-controller, ros2-control

I've successfully re-written a HardwareInterface for my diff_drive robot. So I'm now able to communicate with my real robot with ros2_control. (https://github.com/PaddyCube/hoverboard-driver/tree/ros_2)

Communication is done by USB port, which is hard coded in some config.h file. I'm now looking for a solution, how I can set serial port by parameter of launch command, something like

`ros2 launch my_robot my_diff_Drive.py port:="/dev/ttsUSB2"`

This is an easy task for me when I use nodes and XML launch files. As I'm not familiar with python launch files as well as I don't have a good understanding of ros2_control, I kindly ask some of you to explain how I can achieve this.

My launch file currently looks like this

```
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument, RegisterEventHandler
from launch.conditions import IfCondition
from launch.event_handlers import OnProcessExit
from launch.substitutions import Command, FindExecutable, PathJoinSubstitution, LaunchConfiguration

from launch_ros.actions import Node
from launch_ros.substitutions import FindPackageShare


def generate_launch_description():
    # Declare arguments
    declared_arguments = []
    declared_arguments.append(
        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            "gui",
            default_value="true",
            description="Start RViz2 automatically with this launch file.",
        )
    )

    # Initialize Arguments
    gui = LaunchConfiguration("gui")

    # Get URDF via xacro
    robot_description_content = Command(
        [
            PathJoinSubstitution([FindExecutable(name="xacro")]),
            " ",
            PathJoinSubstitution(
                [FindPackageShare("hoverboard_driver"), "urdf", "diffbot.urdf.xacro"]
            ),
        ]
    )
    robot_description = {"robot_description": robot_description_content}

    robot_controllers = PathJoinSubstitution(
        [
            FindPackageShare("hoverboard_driver"),
            "config",
            "hoverboard_controllers.yaml",
        ]
    )
   # rviz_config_file = PathJoinSubstitution(
   #     [FindPackageShare("ros2_control_demo_description"), "diffbot/rviz", "diffbot.rviz"]
   # )

    control_node = Node(
        package="controller_manager",
        executable="ros2_control_node",
        parameters=[robot_description, robot_controllers],
        output="both",
    )
    robot_state_pub_node = Node(
        package="robot_state_publisher",
        executable="robot_state_publisher",
        output="both",
        parameters=[robot_description],
        remappings=[
            ("/diff_drive_controller/cmd_vel_unstamped", "/cmd_vel"),
        ],
    )
    #rviz_node = Node(
    #    package="rviz2",
    #    executable="rviz2",
    #    name="rviz2",
    #    output="log",
    #    arguments=["-d", rviz_config_file],
    #    condition=IfCondition(gui),
    #)

    joint_state_broadcaster_spawner = Node(
        package="controller_manager",
        executable="spawner",
        arguments=["joint_state_broadcaster", "--controller-manager", "/controller_manager"],
    )

    robot_controller_spawner = Node(
        package="controller_manager",
        executable="spawner",
        arguments=["hoverboard_base_controller", "--controller-manager", "/controller_manager"],
    )

    # Delay rviz start after `joint_state_broadcaster`
    #delay_rviz_after_joint_state_broadcaster_spawner = RegisterEventHandler(
    #    event_handler=OnProcessExit(
    #        target_action=joint_state_broadcaster_spawner,
    #        on_exit=[rviz_node],
    #    )
    #)

    # Delay start of robot_controller after `joint_state_broadcaster`
    delay_robot_controller_spawner_after_joint_state_broadcaster_spawner = RegisterEventHandler(
        event_handler=OnProcessExit(
            target_action=joint_state_broadcaster_spawner,
            on_exit=[robot_controller_spawner],
        )
    )

    nodes = [
        control_node,
        robot_state_pub_node,
        joint_state_broadcaster_spawner,
       # delay_rviz_after_joint_state_broadcaster_spawner,
        delay_robot_controller_spawner_after_joint_state_broadcaster_spawner,
    ]

    return LaunchDescription(declared_arguments + nodes)
```

and in on_acitvate method, here I want to use the parameter

````
      const rclcpp_lifecycle::State & /*previous_state*/)
  {
====>>> GET PORT FROM LAUNCH PARAMETER INSTEAD <<<=====
    port = DEFAULT_PORT;
 

...


    if ((port_fd = open(port.c_str(), O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY)) < 0)
    {
      RCLCPP_FATAL(rclcpp::get_logger("hoverboard_driver"), "Cannot open serial port to hoverboard");
      exit(-1);
    }
```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a conceptional issue here: ros2_control hardware components usually don't have a node inside, hence, cannot parse ROS parameters, e.g., set from launch file or CLI.

Two possibilities are:

- You can add a node spinning in the hardware component, but this might harm realtime constraints, e.g., see this [topic-based](https://github.com/PickNikRobotics/topic_based_ros2_control) component.
- Add parameters to our URDf and parse them with the hardware component, as [done in the examples](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_control_demos/blob/ce7497d894114ed9fd796829caa7b696c112c072/example_1/hardware/rrbot.cpp#L39-L41). You can then use xacro arguments to change it from your launch file.

Comment: Thanks Christoph for your input. I already had some issues with the design you mentioned as I need to publish other data (temperature, voltage etc.) as well. To be able to do so, I simply added a new class deriving from rclcpp::Node, which is member of my hardware_interface. This should be what you mentioned as option 1. Works but I don't like it.
Your option 2 sounds more like the way I should go. I wasn't aware that parameters of urdf files can be set by launch argument as well. Still lots to learn.

Comment: "publish other data" sounds like you should have a look on [GPIO interfaces](https://control.ros.org/master/doc/ros2_control/hardware_interface/doc/hardware_interface_types_userdoc.html#gpios): and in [this example](https://control.ros.org/master/doc/ros2_control_demos/example_10/doc/userdoc.html)